# slick slider videos duplicating

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slick.js

I'm using `slick` slider to slide through 6 videos , and play them when they are the current slide, and the videos play but there is only audio, the html 5 player plays no video, and doesn't even start. There seems to be a second video playing in the background, because you can hear the video in the background, but you cannot control it with the video controls. Im using ruby on rails in this project.

hear is the code

```
<%= render 'navs/nav' %>

<div class="homepage-index-slider">

  <div class="slick-codepen">

    <% @videos.each.with_index do |video,index| %>
      <div class = "hes" data-id="<%= video.id %>">
        <video style = "width: 100%; height: auto; " id="my-video" class="video-js<%= index %> pin_image videos-homepage-video-logic<%= index %>" controls
               poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
          <source src="<%= video.mp4.url %>" type='video/mp4'>
          <source src="<%= video.mp4.url %>" type='video/webm'>
          <source src="<%= video.mp4.url %>" type='video/ogg'>
          <p class="vjs-no-js">
            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
          </p>
        </video>
        <a href = "../videos/<%= video.id %>"><%= image_tag video.image.url(:medium), class: "videos-video-chosen-thumbnail-image videos-video-chosen-thumbnail-image#{index}" %></a>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

    var $slickElement = $('.slick-codepen');

    $slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        console.log(i);
    });

    $('.slick-codepen').slick({
        draggable: false,
        accessibility: true,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        speed: 800,
        arrows: true,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        infinite: false,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        onAfterChange: function(e) {
            if( e.currentSlide == 1 ) {
                $(".videos-video-chosen-thumbnail-image1").fadeOut("slow");
                $(".video-js1").get(0).play();
            }
            if( e.currentSlide == 2 ) {
                $(".videos-video-chosen-thumbnail-image2").fadeOut("slow");
                $(".videos-video-chosen-thumbnail-image1").fadeIn("slow");
                $(".video-js1").get(0).pause();
                $(".video-js2").get(0).play();
             }
        }
    });
</script>
```

ok so when the current slide is 1 or 2 the video plays and pauses, it works, but two videos seem to exist for the same video. One is playing in the background and cant be controlled, and the other is the html 5 video but doesnt show anything

[image]

image of the current active video playing in the background, but not showing up and the progress bar is not moving, but if you play it, it will start a new instance of that video. And I thought it was turbolinks, but I disabled turbolinks and still the weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think `slick` slider has a clone element. If you inspect the slider using inspect element you will see something like `.slick-cloned` added for every slide. So I think there is your problem, because you have the same video twice.

You can resolve this problem only if you set the slider not to run in an infinite loop. Then the clones will be removed. For that `slick` has the next *property* and *value*:

```
$('.slick-codepen').slick({
  infinite: false
});
```

You can also look at the documentation **[here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)**.

Comment: @lonut i see the .slick-cloned when i inspect the element, that makes sense that theres a duplicate, but when i said `infinite:false` the slick slider was still cloning the video elements, and essentially doing the same thing. ill try and look for a way to disable this

Comment: @jalen201, I see that in your original code you have `infinite: true`, have you removed that or replaced it with `infinite: false`? I've tested it on this snippet and you can see that it removes the clones http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/725/ when adding `infinite: false`

Comment: sorry i replaced the `infinite:true` with `infinite:false` just now to test it, and i still see the clones, in the inspector. i thought it may be that i have centermode:true on , but thats not it

Comment: @jalen201, maybe it's a browser caching problem. Try to check the page you have in incognito and check there. As you can see at the fiddle I posted in my above comment, it does the trick, so maybe is the cache or maybe is another thing. But `infinite: false` definitely works. Ahh, and also something that may cause `infinite: false` not to work will be the version of it. I think older versions of `slick` do not support this kind of property. So if you use an older version of `slick` maybe you should updated to the latest one.

Comment: @lonut alright i gave that a shot, and still the same cloning, if the answer if to simply change infinite to false, maybe there is something going on internally in my rails app. Ill do some investigating